# Notify source of target changes in TwoWay Binding

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, microsoft-metro

I'm building a Windows Store App and I have a TextBox binded (two-way mode) to a string "title" property of my TaskItem object.

I need to do some processing *after* changes in the UI are made to this TextBox and propagated back to the source.

I'd like to know if there's a way to detect when the target (TextBox's Text property) has changed. I know I can catch this event by handling the TextBox's LostFocus event, but this event is triggered *before* the source is updated.

**Update:**

Binding:

```
<ScrollViewer
            x:Name="itemDetail"
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}">
    <TextBox x:Name="itemTitle" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Class and property:

```
class TaskItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged because I actually don't need changes to be propagated from the source to the target.

I can think of two solutions:

- Is there a way to use [CallerMemberName] on a property's setter? If there is, I may be able to determine whether the "title" was changed by my own code or because of the binding.
- Ditch the two-way binding and update the source manually during the LostFocus event.

Comment: Show the binding and the property. Do you implement INotifyPropertyChange?

Comment: It sounds like you *do* need to propagate changes from the target to the source. You're saying that you don't need that, but your question is implying that you do need it. No? Am I missing something? Why not implement INotifyPropertyChange and be done with it?

Comment: My bad, I meant the opposite, I didn't implement it because I don't need to propagate from the source to the target. Editing it now.

Comment: I think a key question is: what are you trying to do and why - usually if you are questioning something, there's a better way to do it

Comment: the TaskItem's title shown in the UI can be edited. After editing, the changes should be propagated to the source, where I'll catch this event, update the TaskItem in the local DB and send a message to a server with these changes.

Comment: I think you want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger`, probably instead of mode=TwoWay.

Comment: I had already looked into UpdateSourceTrigger, but it's not available for Windows Store Apps. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Set does not get fired when you leave the text box ?

Comment: It does, but there's no way to know whether it was called by my own code (i.e. instantiating the object with a title) or if it was called because the user changed it. That's why I proposed using the [CallerMemberName] in the setter, but I don't think that can be done.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I will try an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TaskItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title 
    { 
       get { return title; } 
       set 
       { 
           if (title == value) return;
           title = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
       }
    }
    public TaskItem (string -title) 
    { title = _title; }  
    // does not fire setter title lower case 
    // but the UI will have this value as ctor fires before render 
    // so get will reference the assigned value of title 
}
```

[Constructor Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Having two setters (one for public use and another for binding) is a little too hacky, but it works.

Comment: Technically is is not two setters.  title = Title; is assign a member variable.  It is the pattern on MSDN site for Member Design Guidelines \ Constuctor Design.  I don't agree it is a hack.  That is one purpose of member variable.  Does it not do exactly what you want?

Comment: Does this mean that I can only assign a title through a constructor? If I understood correctly, the UI will be binded to "Title", whereas my code will have to use `new TaskItem("hi")`

Comment: You can assign title wherever you want.  The difference is that if you assign it in the ctor Title will return the value of title with the it first renders.   After that if you change title then the bound UI object is not notified.  If you change Title then the UI object is notified (if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged).